# сценарий во внешнем файле

Tags: javascript

Сценарий находится во внешнем файле. Происходит ошибка

> script.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'addEventListener' of null
>       at script.js:7 (anonymous) @ script.js:7 load (async) (anonymous) @ script.js:1

***js/script***

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

 document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click', function () {
   location.href = "./2.html";
  });

 document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click', function () {
   location.href = "./1.html";
  });

});
```

***1.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>1</h1>
 <button id="btn1">go to 2</button>
</body>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

***2.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>2</h1>
 <button id="btn2">go to 1</button>
</body>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Если сценарий вополнять в файлах ошибки не происходит.

***1.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>1</h1>
 <button id="btn1">go to 2</button>
</body>
 <script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {

   document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click', function () {
    location.href = "./2.html";
   });

  });
 </script>
</html>
```

***2.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>2</h1>
<button id="btn2">go to 1</button>
</body>
 <script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {

   document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click', function () {
    location.href = "./1.html";
   });

  });
 </script>
</html>
```

Не могу понять, подскажите. Спасибо.

Comment: Так а что Вас удивляет? Вы загружаете `1.html`, в нем загружается ваш скрипт. Документ загружается, скрипт начинает работать. Находит `btn1`, назначает обработчик. Потом ищет `btn2`, чтобы тоже назначить обработчик. Но элемента `btn2` в `1.html` нет, вот и возникает ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте проверку наличия элемента, перед назначением обработчика.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

 var btn1 = document.querySelector('#btn1');
 var btn2 = document.querySelector('#btn2');
  
  if (btn1) {
    btn1.addEventListener('click', function () {
      location.href = "./2.html";
    });
  }
  
  if (btn2) {
    btn2.addEventListener('click', function () {
      location.href = "./1.html";
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Уважаемый Hikikomori! Большое Вам спасибо!